# How do I reduce the time of context switching after waking from sem_wait

Tags: c

I found the time gap of sem_post and sem_wait is at least 50 microseconds.

```
sem_t gSema;
struct timeval gTv;

void *run(void *arg) {
    int result;
    struct timeval tv;
    struct timespec nano = {0, 1};

    while( 1 ) {
        result = sem_trywait(&gSema);
        if(result < 0) {
            nanosleep(&nano, NULL);
            continue;
        }
        if(result == 0) {
            gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
            printf("waken up...elapsed time = %ld\n", (tv.tv_sec - gTv.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (tv.tv_usec - gTv.tv_usec));
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
void *run2(void *arg) {
    int result;
    struct timeval tv;

    while( 1 ) {
        result = sem_wait(&gSema);
        if( result == 0 ) {
            gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
            printf("waken up...elapsed time = %ld\n", (tv.tv_sec - gTv.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (tv.tv_usec - gTv.tv_usec));
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pthread_t thr;
    sem_init(&gSema, 0, 0);
    pthread_create(&thr, NULL, run, NULL);

    while( 1 ) {
        sleep(1);
        gettimeofday(&gTv, NULL);
        sem_post(&gSema);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

At first, when I run the code with run2(), elapsed time is 50 microseconds. Then CPU usage is very low.
Second, when I run the code with run() without nanosleep, elapsed time is 0 or 1. But CPU usage is 100% expectably. With nanosleep, elapsed time is 1~50 microseconds.

Is there some better method of low cpu usage AND low latency?

Comment: 50 us?  What are you rinning this on?  On Windows, I see semaphore latencies of ~5us.  'Is there some better method of low cpu usage AND low latency?' - no, else everyone would be using it already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing about 4 microseconds per switch using the `pthread_mutex` and `pthread_cond` functions. The sample code below loops 1 million times (2 million signals) in about 8 seconds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define LOOPS 1000000

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond2 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int done = 0;

void *test( void *arg )
{
    // lock the second mutex before signaling the parent, 
    // so that the parent cannot signal before the child is ready
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex2 );

    for (;;)
    {
        // signal the parent
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
        pthread_cond_signal( &cond1 );
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );

        // wait for the parent to signal back
        pthread_cond_wait( &cond2, &mutex2 );

        // check the done indicator, note that the done indicator is 
        // protected by the second mutex, which the child has locked
        if ( done )
        {
            printf( "done\n" );
            break;
        }
    }

    // release the second mutex and exit
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex2 );
    return NULL;
}

int main( void )
{
    // lock the first mutex before launching the child, 
    // so that the child cannot signal before the parent is ready
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );

    // launch the child thread
    pthread_t child;
    pthread_create( &child, NULL, test, NULL);

    for ( int i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++ )
    {
        // give the user some feedback
        if ( i % 100000 == 0 )
        {
            printf( "%7d\r", i );
            fflush( stdout );
        }

        // wait for a signal from the child
        pthread_cond_wait( &cond1, &mutex1 );

        // lock the second mutex and signal the child, 
        // setting the done indicator if needed
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex2 );
        if ( i == LOOPS - 1 )
        {
            printf( "%7d\n", i + 1 );
            done = 1;
        }
        pthread_cond_signal( &cond2 );
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex2 );
    }

    // release the first mutex, and wait for the child to finish
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
    pthread_join( child, NULL );
}
```

Comment: 4us is what I would expect, yes. Not sure how OP managed to get 50us for sema latency:(

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of the low latency. The key is the sleep function.
50 usec is not the latency of sem_wait() but the latency of context switching. When a process runs some code that contains such a sleep() like above, CPU switches the process into another. In the case of 'busy' process, I saw that the latency of sem_wait() is about 1~5 usec.

Surely sem_wait() can cause a context switching by itself. But sem_wait() of busy process causes busy wait, I guess. Right?

Thank you, all!

Answer (score 0):

For non real-time thread, there is a fixed `time slack`, which is 50 us by default (see `/proc/self/timerslack_ns` and description about this [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/procfs.5.html)).

I guess your latency measurement does not count the time of  context switch, but this system time slack.

P.S. use clock_gettime() to get preciser time.